# How can I check if the network has change state during run time of my android application?

Tags: java, android

I'am developing an application for android, which needs network in order to retrieve some information from an xml file. I've got this code, that looking for if the users has enabled the network:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I use this function this way:

```
boolean connected = isOnline(); 

    if(connected) 
        getLocation(); 
    else
        showDialogNetwork();
```

The function  **showDialogNetwork()**:

```
    public void showDialogNetwork() {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)  
    .setMessage("No network")  
    .setTitle("Error")  
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // launch settings
                Intent settings = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(settings);
            }  
        })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                // finish activity
                finish();
            }  
        })
    .show();
}
```

If the network on the device is disabled the **showDialogNetwork()** will open the network tab in the settings menu. But when the users turn on the WiFi, and the application is running in the background, it doesn't "understand" that the network is turned on. I need the "kill" the app after the network is turned on, to get the information from the internet. How can I constantly check if the network has change state during run time of my application? Thanks in advance, guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` with an `IntentFilter` which 'listens' for...

```
WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION
```

You can either register for that in code or if you register the `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest then use the following for the `<intent-filter>`

```
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
```

See [WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)

To also monitor mobile Internet connectivity change you would 'listen' for...

[ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

In this case use the following in the manifest...

```
android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also listen to changes to your Data Connection using the TelephonyManager -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onDataConnectionStateChanged(int)

Even better, register for android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcast action which includes wifi, data etc  -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourapp.receivers.ConnectionChangeReceiver"
          android:label="Connection">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```